# Different Aspects to handle different Exceptions

Tags: c#, postsharp, onexception

From the reading that I have done, I expected that I would be able to create different Aspects inherited from OnExceptionAspect that would allow me to handle different Exceptions differently in my code.

To this end I have created two Aspect classes as follows:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class CommonExceptionAspect : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("{0} had an error @ {1}: {2}\n{3}",
        args.Method.Name, DateTime.Now,
        args.Exception.Message, args.Exception.StackTrace);

        Trace.WriteLine(msg);

        if (args.Exception.GetType() != typeof (PppGeneralException))
        {
            throw new Exception("There was a problem");
        }
        else
        {
            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.RethrowException;
        }
    }
}
```

And the other aspect class:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, TargetMemberAttributes = (MulticastAttributes.Public | MulticastAttributes.NonAbstract | MulticastAttributes.Instance | MulticastAttributes.UserGenerated))] 
public class AuthenticationExceptionAspect : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("{0} had an error @ {1}: {2}\n{3}",
        args.Method.Name, DateTime.Now,
        args.Exception.Message, args.Exception.StackTrace);

        Trace.WriteLine(msg);

        throw new Exception("You are not authorized!");
    }

    public override Type GetExceptionType(System.Reflection.MethodBase targetMethod)
    {
        return typeof(AuthenticationException);
    }
}
```

My caller methods are as follows:

```
   public void EstablishConnection(string connectionString, DateTime d1, int connections)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (connectionString.Length > 0)
        {
            throw new ExternalException("This is my external exception");
        }
    }

    public void StopDatabase(string connectionString)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        if (connectionString.Length > 0)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException("This is my detailed exception");
        }
        else
        {
            throw  new ArgumentException("This is just an argument exception");
        }
    }
```

I have the following entries in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: CommonExceptionAspect(AspectPriority = 3, AttributePriority = 1)]
[assembly: CommonExceptionAspect(AttributeExclude = true, AspectPriority = 3, AttributePriority = 0, AttributeTargetMembers = "ConsoleApplication3.ConnectionManager.StopDatabase", AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
[assembly: AuthenticationExceptionAspect(AspectPriority = 1)]
```

My expectation was that when the first caller method raise the "ExternalException" the OnException method of the "CommonExceptionAspect" would handle it. And when the "AuthenticationException" was raised from the second caller method, OnException method of the "AuthenticationExceptionAspect".

But in both scenarios the call goes to the "CommonExceptionAspect". Could someone please point me what I am doing wrong? If this understanding is incorrect and if this scenario is at all possible to achieve.

Thanks loads in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of `AspectPriority` the higher number means that the aspect (or more precisely the transformation) would be applied first. Therefore in your case you are applying the `CommonExceptionAspect` first and this aspect would receive all exceptions regardless of the other aspect.

You need to set the priorities other way around.

As a sidenote - composition of multiple OnException (or OnMethodBoundary) aspects does not create single try-catch block with multiple catch statements, but will create multiple nested try-catch blocks. Thus, the behavior can be different.

Comment: Also, worth noting that if I raise a general exception from the AuthenticationExceptionAspect then it get caught in the CommonExceptionAspect which again hides the actual information I wanted to pass in the exception raised from AuthenticationExceptionAspect. Raising a specific type of exceptions which can  be ignored in the CommonExceptionAspect and setting the FlowBehavior to Rethrow allowed to work around this. Thanks again!